# Can you critical hit while sprinting in Minecraft Java 1.9+?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have researched this and found many varying answers, can somebody please clarify. *Is it possible to critical hit, after jumping, while in the air, while sprinting?* Because some guides say to release the w key and then press it again. I'm not sure, thanks.

Comment: By 1.9+ Do you mean up until 1.18.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot critical hit while moving faster than walking in Java Edition.

[Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Critical_hit) [emphasis added]

> The requirements for a melee critical hit are:
>
> - A player must be falling.
> - A player must not be on the ground.
> - A player must not be on a ladder or any type of vine.
> - A player must not be in water.
> - A player must not be affected by blindness.
> - A player must not be affected by Slow Falling.
> - A player must not be riding an entity.
> - **A player must not be faster than walking (like flying or sprinting.‌ [Java Edition only] )**
> - A base attack must not be reduced to 84.8% damage or lower due to cooldown.‌ [Java Edition only]

Comment: Okay, I looked into this, and it's inconsistent as hell. [In both](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IojuRULXtJc) (0:10 for fullspeed forwards crit) of [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DZBho2-3Ns) I was able to crit the horse while sprinting - something that **should be impossible**. It's possible that instead there's a speed cap, somewhere, that alters a hit from a critical hit to a "strong" hit, but that wouldn't explain 0:10 in the first video, where I was not in range to get pushed back by the horse yet was sprinting and got a crit anyway.

Comment: Yep: [here's one I got at full speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67JsSAt9120). I don't know what's going on, but the wiki isn't entirely correct in its statement.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are technically right. When sprinting (regardless of whether you jump or not), you instead perform a "strong attack" that deals a ton of additional knockback and almost as much damage as a critical hit (but not quite). Using a netherite sword, a critical hit brings a villager (with a base health of 20, or the same as a player) down to 8 points of health (so -12), whereas a sprint attack brings it to 12 points of health (-8). A sweeping attack also appeared to bring it to 12 health (-8), and a quick hit (as in rapidly clicking) seems to range anywhere from 1 to 8 damage based on how long you recharge (up to the max of 8 resulting in a sweeping attack).

Comment: "almost as much damage as a critical hit" - it's actually the same as a fully charged hit.

Comment: Yea, but doing a fully charged hit instead performs the sweeping blow attack

Answer (score 0):

<s>Sprinting makes no difference to whether a critical hit lands or not. The only conditions are that you must be **falling**, not just in the air.</s>

EDIT: This answer is wrong. My understanding of the game is outdated, heavily, but I've kept it up as one of the other answers refers to it.